# Putting an array into alphabetical order vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a file filled with team names and scores set out like so:

```
Team A
43
65
39
Team B
72
68
62
...
```

I thought the best way would be to take them out and place them into an array (other suggestions would be helpful). I want to display the teams in alphabetical order wity the highest score. I was thinking I would trim everything but the first letter or the name and use a char function to turn into a number then compare. How would this work or are there better ideas? Also how would I find the highest score?

Thanks and replies would be appreciated. I am new to visual basic and programming in general so simple is best even if its slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List`

```
'You can also store Integers, Doubles, whatever you like
Dim lstNames As New List(Of String)

lstNames.Add("Bean")
lstNames.Add("Apple")
lstNames.Add("Corn")

lstNames.Sort()

'Apple
'Bean
'Corn
```

---

```
Dim lstScores As New List(Of Integer)

lstScores.Add(10)
lstScores.Add(100)
lstScores.Add(1)

lstScores.Sort()

'1
'10
'100
```

`List` has a sort function built-in for you. It's alphabetical by default, but you can create your own.

If you stored integers, the highest value would be at the end.

```
Dim nHighestScore As Integer = lstScores.Last
```

Comment: Is there anything else I need other than this because it doesn't work

Comment: Well I can't see your code, so I don't know what you're doing. In general, you have to tailor the above code to yours. You might need trickier manipulation, etc. I won't know until I see yours.

Comment: Might want to at least try to set it up in your own code. A two second google search brought up how to get the information into a list, then how to use the built in function to order it.   -Could try Linq

Answer (score 0):

I've got some code for you- read the comments for more info - though i am not sure how your file is formatted because someone edited your post. The two solutions are below.

```
    Dim filetext As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filename) 'read your file
    Dim teamlist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) 'Just a variable, using it later

    Dim YourFileIsSeperatedByNewline As Boolean = False

    If YourFileIsSeperatedByNewline Then
        Dim splitfile As String() = Split(filetext, vbCrLf) 'Split your file, assuming that it is seperated by newline
        If splitfile.Count = 0 Then : End If 'insert some exit because there are no items
        Dim current As Integer = 0 'So you know which you are at
        Dim scorelist(3) As Integer 'no of scores must be exactly 3
        Dim team As String = ""
        For i = 0 To splitfile.Count - 1
            If current = 0 Then
                team &= splitfile(i)
            ElseIf current = 1 Or current = 2 Then
                scorelist(current - 1) = splitfile(i)
            Else
                scorelist(current - 1) = splitfile(i) 'One more
                teamlist.Add(team & " " & Math.Max(Math.Max(scorelist(0), scorelist(1)), scorelist(2)))
                current = -1 'make current=0 the next loop
                team = "" 'Reset
            End If
            current += 1
        Next
    Else
        'If your file is seperated by spaces (Team A ... ... ...) and so on
        Dim splitfile = Split(filetext, " ")
        If splitfile.Count = 0 Then : End If 'insert some exit because there are no items
        Dim current As Integer = 0 'So you know which you are at
        Dim scorelist(3) As Integer 'no of scores must be exactly 3
        Dim team As String = ""
        For i = 0 To splitfile.Count - 1
            If current = 0 Or current = 1 Then
                team &= splitfile(i)
            ElseIf current = 2 Or current = 3 Then
                scorelist(current - 2) = splitfile(i)
            Else
                scorelist(current - 2) = splitfile(i) 'One more
                teamlist.Add(team & " " & Math.Max(Math.Max(scorelist(0), scorelist(1)), scorelist(2)))
                current = -1 'make current=0 the next loop
                team = "" 'Reset
            End If
            current += 1
        Next
    End If


    teamlist.Sort()
    MsgBox(Join(teamlist.ToArray, vbCrLf)) 'then display teamlist (can be changed)
```